# New gulp-ruby-sass alpha task failing

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I've used the gulp-ruby-sass a number of times, however on this new project my task is failing with the following error:

```
gulp-ruby-sass stderr: OptionParser::NeedlessArgument: needless argument: --sourcemap=none  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Here's my **package.json**

```
{
"name": "new",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

**Gulpfile.js:**

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCSS   = require('gulp-minify-css');
var ngannotate  = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var sass        = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var connect     = require('gulp-connect');
var gutil       = require('gulp-util');

var paths = {
  js: ['assets/js/app.js', 'assets/js/controllers/*.js', 'assets/js/services/*.js', 'assets/js/directives/*.js'],
  sass: ['assets/css/styles.scss']
};

//SASS task
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return sass (paths.sass)
      .pipe(concat('all.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
      .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

**styles.scss:**

```
@import "modules/mixins.scss";
@import "modules/vars.scss";    
@import "modules/reset.scss";    
@import "modules/header.scss";
@import "modules/footer.scss";
```

Folder structure is:

```
app
    assets
        css
            modules
                header.scss
                footer.scss
                etc....
            styles.scss (this is outside of the modules folder)
```

Like I said, ive used this plugin a number of times over the past year. It seems this 'alpha' version has caused a lot of issues.

Has anyone experienced this issue? How can I resolve.

My whole project is on halt until this is resolved :(

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/196

Comment: Fixed - had an out of data version of SASS!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Solved - had an out of data version of SASS. Needs to be greater than v3.4